# Why does the Insertion fails with error code 17004 even if I added jdbcType?

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, mybatis

I have been dealing with insertion, which keeps failing with error code 17004.

I thought the problem was because there is a "select" inside the "insert", but in Oracle SQL developer, it worked. The error code 17004 is due to null value issue, so I also added jdbcType to every parameter I give, and yet it is still not working.

This is my SQL for insertion that failed with error code 17004.

```
<insert id="registerNewPenalty" parameterType="TbAdhPenaltyTreatVO">
INSERT INTO
    TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT
            TO_CHAR(NVL(MAX(HISTNO), 0) + 1) AS MAXSEQ
        FROM
            TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT
     ),
    #{penaltytpcd, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{regdt, jdbcType=DATE},
    #{occurdt, jdbcType=DATE},
    #{runvioltpcd, jdbcType=DATE},
    #{compid, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    #{routeid, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    #{busid, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    'bmscenter',
    NULL,
    #{treat_detail, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    '0'
)
</insert>
```

And this is my TbAdhPenaltyTreatVO.

```
public class TbAdhPenaltyTreatVO {
private String histno;          //  NUMBER(10,0)        Yes     1   
private String penaltytpcd;     //  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)    Yes     2   
private String regdt;           //  DATE                Yes     3   
private String occurdt;         //  DATE                Yes     4   
private String runvioltpcd;     //  VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)    Yes     5   
private String compid;          //  NUMBER(6,0)         Yes     6   
private String routeid;         //  NUMBER(9,0)         Yes     7   
private String busid;           //  NUMBER(9,0)         Yes     8   
private String treat_userid;    //  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes     9   
private String treat_orgnm;     //  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes     10  
private String treat_detail;    //  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     11  
private String treatyn;         //  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)    Yes     12


... getters and setters below
```

The query what I expected and worked in Oracle SQL Developer was:

```
INSERT INTO tb_adh_penaltytreat
VALUES   (1,
         '1',
         SYSDATE,
         To_date('2017/11/02 04:40:47', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),
         '13',
         '164003',
         '165000310',
         '7012268',
         'bmscenter',
         NULL,
         '......',
         '0');
```

For the query at the top, the query ended with the log below:

```
[2019-01-29 16:03:17] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
[2019-01-29 16:03:17] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@777f6077]
[2019-01-29 16:03:17] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.20:1521:orcl, UserName=ICBIS_AGO, Oracle JDBC driver] will be managed by Spring
[2019-01-29 16:03:17] DEBUG: PENALTY.registerNewPenalty - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT VALUES ( ( SELECT TO_CHAR(NVL(MAX(HISTNO), 0) + 1) AS MAXSEQ FROM TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT ), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'bmscenter', NULL, ?, '0' ) 
[2019-01-29 16:03:17] DEBUG: PENALTY.registerNewPenalty - ==> Parameters: 1(String), null, 2017-11-02 05:54:35.0(String), 13(String), 166012(String), 165000067(String), 7016047(String), this is for test.(String)
[2019-01-29 16:03:17] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@777f6077]
```

I don't know what the problem is, yet suspecting it might be the problem of "select".
Thank you for reading.

**UPDATE**

I changed my query like this:

```
    <insert id="registerNewPenalty" parameterType="TbAdhPenaltyTreatVO">
    INSERT INTO
    TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT (
        HISTNO,
        PENALTYTPCD,
        REGDT,
        OCCURDT,
        RUNVIOLTPCD,
        COMPID,
        ROUTEID,
        BUSID,
        TREAT_USERID,
        TREAT_ORGNM,
        TREAT_DETAIL,
        TREATYN
    )
    VALUES (
    (
        SELECT
            TO_CHAR(NVL(MAX(HISTNO), 0) + 1) AS MAXSEQ
        FROM
            TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT
     ),
    #{penaltytpcd, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    SYSDATE,
    #{occurdt, jdbcType=DATE},
    #{runvioltpcd, jdbcType=DATE},
    #{compid, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    #{routeid, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    #{busid, jdbcType=INTEGER},
    'bmscenter',
    NULL,
    #{treat_detail, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    '0'
    )
    </insert>
```

And the query ended with this debug log:

```
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5f587204]
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.20:1521:orcl, UserName=ICBIS_AGO, Oracle JDBC driver] will be managed by Spring
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: PENALTY.registerNewPenalty - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT ( HISTNO, PENALTYTPCD, REGDT, OCCURDT, RUNVIOLTPCD, COMPID, ROUTEID, BUSID, TREAT_USERID, TREAT_ORGNM, TREAT_DETAIL, TREATYN ) VALUES ( ( SELECT TO_CHAR(NVL(MAX(HISTNO), 0) + 1) AS MAXSEQ FROM TB_ADH_PENALTYTREAT ), ?, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'bmscenter', NULL, ?, '0' ) 
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: PENALTY.registerNewPenalty - ==> Parameters: 1(String), 2017-11-02 05:54:35.0(String), 13(String), 166012(String), 165000067(String), 7016047(String), This data is for test.(String)
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5f587204]
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '1861', will now try the fallback translator
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator - Extracted SQL state class '22' from value '22008'
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5f587204]
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5f587204]
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.20:1521:orcl, UserName=ICBIS_AGO, Oracle JDBC driver]
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.20:1521:orcl, UserName=ICBIS_AGO, Oracle JDBC driver] after transaction
[2019-01-30 09:15:47] DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

** 2nd UPDATE **

I have changed `#{occurdt, jdbcType=DATE}` into NULL, and the insertion was successful. So I think the problem lies in `#{occurdt, jdbcType=DATE}`.

Comment: List the columns when you are doing an insert.  The problem is likely caused by values going into the "wrong" columns.  Relying on default ordering is very dangerous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did as what you said, yet it still has a problem :( Thank you for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyBatis does not add `TO_DATE` automatically. You need to write the function in the statement.

```sql
TO_DATE(#{occurdt}, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),
```

Another option is to write a custom [type handler](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) that converts String from/to DATE.

```sql
#{occurdt,typeHandler=com.xxx.YourCustomTypeHandler},
```

Changing the property type to `LocalDate` or `Date` also is worth considering if you have control over the VO definition. Then `#{occurdt}` should work.